# How can I source files relative to file?

Tags: vim, neovim

I'm trying to split my `vimrc` up into multiple files - `init.vim`, `keybindings.vim`, `ui.vim`, etc. - but I can't get Vim to source files relative to `init.vim` (it instead sources relative to where I launch Vim from.

This is what I've got at the top of `init.vim`:

```
source keybindings.vim
source ui.vim
```

If I run `vim` from the same directory as those files, it works fine; if I run it from any other directory, I get the following errors:

```
Error detected while processing /path/to/vimrc:
line 1:
E484: Can't open file keybindings.vim
line 2:
E484: Can't open file ui.vim
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Edit: It's worth noting that I'm using NixOS, so I don't know what the absolute paths will be, nor if they would be constant if I found out.

Comment: You know, you can split your .vimrc into plugins (i.e. files dropped into your `~/.vim/plugin/` directory. However, there is no way to control their relative loading order.

Answer (score 14):

I think you can use

```
runtime keybindings.vim
```

Comment: I tried this, but I couldn't get it to work. I'll try to dig deeper into why the particular directory I'm using isn't in the `runtimepath` or if I can put it there somehow.

Answer (score 12):

Source needs the full path, you can however simplify it using something like this :

```
let path = expand('%:p:h')
exec 'source' path . '/keybindings.vim'
```

You can have a look at mine here - https://github.com/dhruvasagar/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/vimrc for reference.

Comment: `<sfile>` instead of `%` for sourced script file.

Answer (score 6):

If the order is not important, you can just put your scripts into `~/.vim/plugin/`, and they will be sourced after `~/.vimrc`. You can check `:scriptnames` output to see what gets sourced when.

You can influence the ordering somewhat via the plugin filenames. For example, I have a `~/.vim/plugin/00plugin-configuration.vim` that configures Vim plugins; the `00...` ensures this is sourced first.

To get finer control, I would instead put the scripts into `~/.vim/`. Vim will ignore them there, but they can easily be addressed via `:runtime`, which looks in all runtimepaths, and `~/.vim/` typically is included in `'runtimepath'`:

```
# .vimrc
runtime init.vim
runtime keybindings.vim
...
```

Relevant help pages: `:help .vimrc` and `:help load-plugins`.

Answer (score 4):

I have met exactly the same issue with you in Neovim. I split my large `init.vim` file into several small vim scripts and I want to source them inside `init.vim`.
This is what I get finally based on @Dhruva Sagar's links:

```
let g:nvim_config_root = stdpath('config')
let g:config_file_list = ['variables.vim',
    \ 'options.vim',
    \ 'autocommands.vim',
    \ 'mappings.vim',
    \ 'plugins.vim',
    \ 'ui.vim'
    \ ]

for f in g:config_file_list
    execute 'source ' . g:nvim_config_root . '/' . f
endfor
```

Answer (score 3):

Building on Dhruva's answer, you can make a function to help out with this

```
function! SourceLocal(relativePath)
  let root = expand('%:p:h')
  let fullPath = root . '/'. a:relativePath
  exec 'source ' . fullPath
endfunction
```

You then use it like

```
call SourceLocal ("yourScript.vim")
```

Answer (score 0):

As none of the solutions works as a real substitute for `source` working globally (on any script, even sourced from `vimrc`), I ended up with this solution and decided to share here, which can be used as a substitute for `source` with relative support, as simple as:

```
Rsource /home/me/.vim/your/file/path
Rsource $HOME/.vim/your/file/path
Rsource your/file/path
Rsource ../your/file/path
```

To use it, this must be defined on your `vimrc` or any file sourced by it before you can use `Rsource`:

```
if !exists('g:RelativeSource')
    function! g:RelativeSource(file)
        let file = expand(a:file)

        " if file is a root path, just source it
        if stridx(file, '/') == 0
            exec 'source ' . file
            return
        endif

        let sfile = expand('<sfile>:p:h')

        " If this is called outside this script, it will contains this script
        " name, this function name, a script_marker then the executing script name
        " In this case we extract just the last part, the script name which called
        " the this function
        let script_marker = '..script '
        let path_index = strridx(sfile, script_marker)

        if path_index == -1
            let path_index = 0
        else
            let path_index += len(script_marker)
        endif

        let path = strpart(sfile,path_index)
        let absolute_path = resolve(path . '/'. file)

        exec 'source ' . absolute_path
    endfunction

    command! -nargs=1 Rsource :call g:RelativeSource(<q-args>)
endif
```

This is safe to be used in any script or plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
function! s:SourceLocal(script)
  let callstack = expand("<stack>")
  let list = split(callstack, '\.\.')
  " list[-1] is SourceLocal function itself
  " list[-2] is the calling script
  let script_name = matchstr(list[-2], '^\(script \)\=\zs.\+\ze\[\d\+\]$')
  let script_path = fnamemodify(script_name, ":p:h")
  execute printf("source %s/%s", script_path, a:script)
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 SourceLocal :call s:SourceLocal(<f-args>)
```

Answer (score -2):

These are all great solutions, and this is what I ended up using.

```
let home = expand('~')
exec 'source' home . '/.config/nvim/prettierConfig.vim'
```